# Find supremum and infimum of a set given by: for $n \in N , k \in N,$. Got supremum, need infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

As in the title, I have to find supremum and infimum of the set $$S=\left\\mid n \in \mathbb N,\, k \in \mathbb N, 2|k\right\}$$

I know that $k^6$ should "grow faster" than $n^2$ if both are natural numbers. Then I can transform that expression into: $$$$ For $n \implies \infty$ I get: $$\frac{n^2}{8n^2}=\frac{1}{8}$$ That would be my supremum. BUT there is a question of infimum and the information that $2|k$. I don't know how to use that information in the process of finding the infimum. Any help would be much appreciated.

Important note: in that case, we take $\mathbb N as \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...\}$ (without $0$).

Comment: Hi, why did you delete the maths contained in several display lines and the title? Could you please revert? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote for $n,k \in \mathbb N$

$$s(n,k)= \frac{n^2k^6}{n^2+8n^2k^6+9}.$$

All the elements of $S$ are less than $1/8$. Now taking $n=1$ and $k=2l$ we have

$$\lim\limits_{l \to \infty} s(1,2l) \to 1/8$$

and $s(1,2l) \in S$ for all $l \in \mathbb N$, proving that $\sup S=1/8$.

Regarding the $\inf$, consider the map

$f(x) = \frac{n^2 x}{n^2 + 8n^2x + 9}$ defined for $x \in [2^6, \infty)$. You have
$$f^\prime(x) = \frac{n^2(n^2 + 8n^2x + 9) - 8n^4x}{(n^2 + 8n^2x + 9)^2}= n^2\frac{n^2+9}{(n^2 + 8n^2x + 9)^2}$$ which is positive, proving that f achieve its minimum when $x=2^6$, i.e. $k=2$. We get

$$s(n, k) \ge \frac{64n^2}{513n^2+9}$$ for $n,k \in \mathbb N$ when $k$ is even. Analyzing the map $g(x) = \frac{64x}{513x+9}$ for $x \in [1,\infty)$, you'll find that it is increasing on that interval. Therefore its minimim is achieved for $x=1$ and the minimum of $S$ is $s(1,2)=\frac{32}{261}$.

Comment: I think it's good. That inf was indeed quite trivial. Are you sure with that supremum though? The fact that concerns me is that we both did not use the information about 2|k.

Comment: I did use the fact that $2 |k$: $k=2l$ is a multiple of $2$.

Comment: Yeah but you could as well not use it and it would work fine, am I right? Besides that, I just foud out that in the case of that problem I need to take $\mathbb{N}$ starting from 1.

Comment: Some update in the answer based on the definition of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I have already figured out the answer but that's very kind of you!